# Loading external JSON file as a javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I thought this question would be trivial but I just can't seem to find an answer.
A website (different origin, no control over it) is making available some JSON files. I want some variables of my script to grab the content of those files. I don't care whether it is done synchrnously or not. How would you go ?

Comment: You could use jsonp? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP or jQuery way http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: As far as I know there is none for the browser. From JavaScript of corse.

Comment: JSONP is some kind of a hack, and my request seems so ... simple and pertinent. Can't believe we don't have that yet :(

Comment: Yea, I know, and since JS debuggers run in the browser it easy to hack it also, so ir doesn't make any sense at all sometimes. =) But you have no other choice except using flash... =DDD Below guy answered your question. =)

Comment: @Cystack the reason you cannot just make an ajax call to a different domain is for security measures.

Comment: And now if I host it on my server, what would the snippet be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using JSONP consist of using your url, with parameters, and add a script file to your page

> www.example.com/process?value=1&callback=Func

add the script to your page.

```
var url = "www.example.com/process?value=1&callback=Func";
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type= ' text/javascript';
script.src = url;
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(script);
```

now you can use the call back function or access the variables that were added from this script.

**UPDATE**

At the end of your jsonp script you can call your call back function 
Ex: php

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['callback'])) {
    echo $_GET['callback']."();";
    // Func(); // will call your function and use your variables.
}
```

Comment: Thanks... JSONP is the way then... And now if I host it on my server, what would the snippet be ?

Comment: This implies that I have control over the "example.com" server... and I don't !

Comment: @Cystack you said "now if I host it on my server" so i thought you had control over it. in that case you will have to read the documentation of the api you are using.

Comment: You don't need JSONP if you host it on your own server. A simple async call does the job. The only thing you need is to watch for the links you make your call to. You think you are refering to your server but you can refer to it as it would seem a different domain to browsers, so watch out with that! =)

Answer (score 1):

If the remote host does not supply [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing), then you will need to place a server-side component on your own domain which fetches the JSON for you and serves it locally.